# How to correctly handle multiple Set-Cookie headers in Hyper?

Tags: http-headers, rust, hyper

I'm using Hyper to send HTTP requests, but when multiple cookies are included in the response, Hyper will combine them to one which then fails the parsing procedure.

For example, here's a simple PHP script

```php
<?php

setcookie("hello", "world");
setcookie("foo", "bar");
```

Response using curl:

```
$ curl -sLD - http://local.example.com/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 09:24:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/7.0.14
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.14
Set-Cookie: hello=world
Set-Cookie: foo=bar
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

However for the following Rust code:

```
let client = Client::new();
let response = client.get("http://local.example.com/test.php")
    .send()
    .unwrap();
println!("{:?}", response);
for header in response.headers.iter() {
    println!("{}: {}", header.name(), header.value_string());
}
```

...the output will be:

```
Response { status: Ok, headers: Headers { Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 09:31:54 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/7.0.14, X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.14, Set-Cookie: hello=worldfoo=bar, Content-Length: 0, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, }, version: Http11, url: "http://local.example.com/test.php", status_raw: RawStatus(200, "OK"), message: Http11Message { is_proxied: false, method: None, stream: Wrapper { obj: Some(Reading(SizedReader(remaining=0))) } } }
Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 09:31:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/7.0.14
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.14
Set-Cookie: hello=worldfoo=bar
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This seems to be really weird to me. I used Wireshark to capture the response and there're **two** `Set-Cookie` headers in it. I also checked the Hyper documentation but got no clue...

I noticed Hyper internally uses a `VecMap<HeaderName, Item>` to store the headers. So they concatenate the them to one? Then how should I divide them into individual cookies afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Hyper prefers to keep the cookies together in order to make it easier do some extra stuff with them, like checking a cryptographic signature with [`CookieJar`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.9.14/hyper/header/struct.CookieJar.html) (cf. [this implementation outline](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/pull/71#issuecomment-58246056)).

Another reason might be to keep the API simple. Headers in Hyper are indexed by type and you can only get a single instance of that type with [`Headers::get`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.9.14/hyper/header/struct.Headers.html#method.get).

In Hyper, you'd usually access a header by using a corresponding type. In this case the type is [`SetCookie`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.9.14/hyper/header/struct.SetCookie.html). For example:

```
if let Some (&SetCookie (ref cookies)) = response.headers.get() {
    for cookie in cookies.iter() {
        println! ("Got a cookie. Name: {}. Value: {}.", cookie.name, cookie.value);
    }
}
```

Accessing the raw header value of Set-Cookie makes less sense, because then you'll have to reimplement a proper parsing of quotes and cookie attributes (cf. [RFC 6265, 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)).

---

P.S. Note that in Hyper 10 the cookie is no longer parsed, [because](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/commit/f22701f7e7258ad4a26645eba47a3d374e452e86) the crate that was used for the parsing triggers the openssl dependency hell.

Comment: cool, this is really helpful, thanks. I think `hyper` may prefer combining the cookies in one header field with semicolon split... (http://hyper.rs/hyper/async/hyper/header/struct.Cookie.html)

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, getting at code reuse with the server side of the library sounds like another good reason to keep the cookies together.